# Plotting multiple charts based on stored functions

Tags: r, function, charts, statistics, rstudio

In R, I'm trying to plot multiple charts based on stored functions (I'm pretty new to programming with R, so that might not totally make sense). Basically, I've created some charts and stored them in a function that can be easily run with new data. I want to retain that functionality while adding the ability to render multiple charts in one render. I'd like it to end up something like this http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/images/layout1.jpg

I've run the code below, but it just produces multiple instances of each graph (or replaces each graph with the new rendering).

So my question is this: what am I doing wrong? Does anyone out there know how I can generate four graphs to be placed in one view (like the link above) using the following code and functions? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Note: the second bit of code has two siblings. I also have a pie chart I haven't included, but it's mentioned in the following code.

Here's the code I've been working with:

```
attach(ES)
par=(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot=(mapFunctionRead())
plot=(mapFunctionSkim())
plot=(mapFunctionDelete())
plot=(pieChart())
```

And Here's a sample function:

```
mapFunctionRead<-function(){
# draw world map
map(database="world", bg="#d4d5d1", fill = TRUE, col="#ffffff",myborder = 0)

################# For Read ####################
# Draw circles
symbols(mtReadLong, mtReadLat, circles=rep(1, length(mtReadLong)), inches=0.005, add=TRUE)

# assign numerical value that's based on the amount of time read
radiusRead<-sqrt(mtReadSec/pi)

# draw circles with fill and border
symbols(mtReadLong, mtReadLat, bg="#4173a5", fg="#5589c7", lwd=0.5, circles=radiusRead, inches=0.05, add=TRUE)
}
################# Displays data on world map for SKIM ###################### 
mapFunctionSkim<-function(){
 # draw world map
 map(database="world", bg="#d4d5d1", fill = TRUE, col="#ffffff",myborder = 0)

################# For Skim ####################
# Draw circles
symbols(mtSkimLong, mtSkimLat, circles=rep(1, length(mtSkimLong)), inches=0.005, add=TRUE)

# assign numerical value that's based on the amount of time read
radiusSkim<-sqrt(mtSkimSec/pi)

# draw circles with fill and border
symbols(mtSkimLong, mtSkimLat, bg="#ead57d", fg="#ead57d", lwd=0.5, circles=radiusSkim, inches=0.05, add=TRUE)
}

################# Displays data on world map for DELETE ###################### 
mapFunctionDelete<-function(){
# draw world map
map(database="world", bg="#d4d5d1", fill = TRUE, col="#ffffff",myborder = 0)

################# For Delete ####################
# Draw circles
symbols(mtDeleteLong, mtDeleteLat, circles=rep(1, length(mtDeleteLong)), inches=0.005, add=TRUE)

# assign numerical value that's based on the amount of time read
radiusDelete<-sqrt(mtDeleteSec/pi)

# draw circles with fill and border
symbols(mtDeleteLong, mtDeleteLat, bg="#77223c", fg="#9c1b3e", lwd=0.5, circles=radiusDelete, inches=0.05, add=TRUE)
}
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question here?

Comment: Sorry about that. I've updated my original question with an actual question.

My code that I pasted above isn't working — the charts are rendered, but they're being stacked. I would like to render them all out on a single page, in rows of two. I've been working at it but every piece of code I've added or replaced has simply generated issues with my renders. So my question is what am I doing wrong, and how can I generate four charts with the above code. The map function in the second paragraph has two siblings. There's also a pie graph.

Comment: what is mapFunctionskim or mapFunctionDelete. From what you've provided these functions don't exist.

Comment: @miles2know Hey, I've added what the other two functions are. They're basically just the same function calling other information. I haven't refined this down to a single function — like I said, I'm new to R, and am unsure how you build functions like that in it.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: do you think mtReadLong() is a function or a variable?

Comment: you are working too hard. look into closures.

Comment: @miles2know mtReadlong is a variable that's defined earlier on.

Thanks for the advice on closures. Well really, thanks for all of the advice — it has helped out a lot. I'll look into closures and, afterwards, experiment with the bit you've provided below..

Answer (score 0):

Well I agree with @MrFlick. You might want to think of providing arguments to your map functions. For example.

```
     
    library(maps)
    mfunc <- function(x,y){
    map(database = x, bg = y)
    }
    mfunc(x = "world", y = "#d4d5d1")
```

Then once all your map functions are defined you can use par(mfrow = c(a,b)). But just based on the info you have provided I'm not really sure what you want. Best of luck though.

Comment: so with such a long question you should have given some insight on (mtReadLong) and lat. I wanted to start computing, but I know without doubt that your plotting difficulties have to do with over thinking. your problem is understanding when a new graphics device gets opened.